# Table row on click jQuery addClass not working with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dynamic table in Bootstrap. The idea is to change row color on click. Firebug tells me that the "selectedRow" class is being applied, but rows do not change color.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:  color: rgb(244, 244, 243);">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="daTable" class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr><th>xxxxx</th>
                    <th>yyyyy</th></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var tabl = document.getElementById("daTable");
for (var i = 0; i <data.length; i++) {
    var d= data[i];
    tableRow(tabl, [d.field1, d.field2]);           
}

$(tabl).on('click', '.clickable-row', function(event) {
    $(this).addClass("selectedRow");
    $(this).find('td').addClass("selectedRow");    
});
```

CSS

```
.selectedRow {
    background-color:red !important;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't see where are you applying the `clickable-row` class to the table rows. What if you just do:

```
$('#daTable tr').on('click', function(event) {
     $(this).toggleClass("selectedRow");
});
```

Comment: Just as an addition, you should restrict the selector to `tbody` only.

Answer (score 0):

my bad. there was a typo in the css. thanks anyway